# SQL Server 2008 READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT equivalent in IBM DB2 9.7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, db2, read-committed-snapshot

Is there an equivalent setting for IBM DB2 9.7 as there is for SQL Server 2008? The parameter is READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT which can be set to ON and apparently affects locking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat equivalent would be to set the database configuration parameter `CUR_COMMIT` ("currently committed") to `ON`, however, this does not eliminate locks completely. It does eliminate lock waits though, as queries, instead of waiting on exclusive locks, will fetch previously committed versions of the locked rows.